How does USB serial firmware update over 3 wires work?
I have a receiver for a radio-controlled model that is able to have its firmware updated using a manufacturer supplied USB serial device over a three wire servo cable (+ve, gnd, signal).
I'm familiar with a four wire serial interfaces over UART (+ve, gnd, txd, rxd), but would like to learn how the above technique works. I assume it must be using half-duplex and "sharing" the signal wire, whilst also powering the receiver.
Could someone point me in the right direction to understand more about what the schematic for the "three wire setup" would look like on both sides and how it works please?
Update 1 (Host Side Schematic Identified):
A schematic has been found for the host side of the connection. With this schematic in mind, please could someone explain the below as my understanding of electronics/embedded programming is still in its infancy?

How does this circuit work from an electrical standpoint?
What circuit would be needed on the MCU side of the link to "break out" the connection back into 4 wires (+ve, gnd, tx, rx) so that it could be connected to the UART of an MCU?
Given most MCUs run at 3.3v and the USB is at 5V, presumably level shifting would needed on the MCU side?



It's impossible for us to tell without a bit of reverse engineering effort - there are a few potential options for implementing bidirectional communication, if that's actually what it's doing - are you sure it's not one-way only? The most electrically straight forward is a strict request/response protocol, with only one end driving the bus at a time.

It looks conceptually similar to the MAv Sense USB/C interface, but there seems to be very little out there about either - reviews, teardowns, reverse engineering, etc... (perhaps I'm looking for the wrong thing...)

The PC (USB side) is able to receive some data from the receiver (e.g. current firmware version) so I think it is probably bi-directional but with a clear request/response. I was wondering if it was triggering the in-system programmer on the receiver MCU and then using that to rewrite the firmware. I think a typical ISP bootloader would have clear request/response boundaries?

It does look similar to the MAv Sense, and indeed I am aware of other devices that do something very similar. As such, it must be a well understood hardware/software pattern - I just can't seem to find any information with searching.

"I was wondering if it was triggering the in-system programmer on the receiver MCU" - almost certainly not, they'll likely have a custom bootloader that can handle the interface appropriately

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

It can work in many different ways.
It looks like the port on the module is an external input. But it does not matter.
Physically, it may be a single bidirectional data wire, with the USB interface providing ground and supply for programming. An MCU can even detect if the supply is provided only from that port and go into update mode. Bidirectional pen-collector or open-drain communications on single wire has been used for decades.
The protocol does not matter either - as long as there is some trigger that makes it go into update mode. For example, the USB plug may use a handshake pin to wiggle the power to the module. The module might wait for a couple of seconds for special input before resuming normal operations.
The protocol could also be anything. Just UART, as half-duplex single wire. This has been used by smart cards with MCUs  for decades as well.
The protocol could be PWM or PPM what servos use anyway. The USB plug could contain a MCU to act as an interface between the module and USB plug. Or each bit of each byte might be used for transmitting different pulse patterns that resemble data.
Which reminds me about 1-Wire protocol by Maxim. The host always sends a pulse for a bit, the pulse can be short or long. When host wants to read data out from device, the device can lengthen short pulses to long pulses which the host can detect.
So here are just many examples how it could work or how I would do it. I have no knowledge in which specific way this manufacturer implemented it, or if it even is half duplex on single wire. Generally, it usually is the simplest method providing reasonable performance at lowest possible price for hobbyist products so it can't be very complex as an interface.
The data transmitted over the interface is another thing. As they have a custom PC software, they could use any complex cryptograhy methods to make sure that your module has an acceptable serial number or their servers could send you the firmware encrypted based on your module serial number, which only can be decoded by your module with that serial number. Or the module could refuse to accept firmware signed with incorrect public/private keys.
So if I had to guess, cheapest option is to have open-drain bi-directional data wire and a half-duplex UART protocol.
Edit: and it is what I expected.

The resistor pulls the line to idle at 5V logic high levl when nobody pulls the line low. Assuming the other end is identical, both ends listen the bus with RX pin and can pull the wire low through the diode to send data. The diode is only needed because the FTDI chip has push-pull TXD output and that's the most simplest way of simulating open-collector interface.

Both ends can be assumed functionally identical and can use same circuit. Or not. Most modern MCUs can support a single TX/RX pin for half-duplex UART. The IO pin can be configured as open-drain.

Not necessarily. Most modern MCUs may include 5V tolerant IO pins so level shifting may not be needed. But it is also possible to have level shifting. There may even be level shifting required if the port is normally used for 5V servo interface that don't work with 3.3V voltage.



Thank you, I appreciate your inputs.

"the FTDI chip has push-pull TXD output" - could you point me toward where this is documented for FTDI chips? I've been checking datasheets but not found it, although it may be I am not looking for the right phrases!

@Scruffers It simply says the TXD is an output. And for all outputs, the sink and source currents are stated. Only in reset the UART interface is tristated. And the general assumption is that an output is an output unless it's somehow special and not a push-pull output. If you want to use this chip or any other UART chip, in most cases, you have TXD output and RXD input. Let me ask, what are you after when you are trying to find if the TXD output type?

I was mainly interested as I was trying to simulate what you described along with the circuit above to learn how it worked.

The OP link points to a device from Jetimodel site, which is used to program "Jeti RC models". A quick search for images on Internet {Jeti model update interface} gives the following home-grown converter:


Thank you, this is very helpful. I have added the schematic to the main question along with some follow up questions that it raises.

@Scruffers, the UART-Jeti "converter" is shown above. If you want to reverse engineer the Jeti side, I suggest to learn LTspice simulator, generate a stimulus in a form of typical UART pattern (including UART driver impedance, and see what kind of signals will be generated at the "signal pin". It likely will be some sort of two-level signaling, so your receiving end must include some level-sensing comparators or something, not just "level shifter". I am not going to do all this legwork, sorry. Maybe you need to look for some patent application from Jeti.
